# Issue with recursive statement

Tags: python, function, recursion

I'm trying to understand the following recursive function.
I would expect to get a return value of `3` when I enter `comb3(3,2)` to the function.

Here is the python code:

```
def comb3(n, k):
  if (k == 0):
    return 1    
  return comb3(n-1, k-1) * n/k;
```

As I understand here is the breakdown:

```
comb3(3, 2) = comb3(3-1, 2-1) * 3/2
              comb3(2, 1) * 1

comb3(2, 1) = comb3(2-1, 1-0) * 2/1
comb3(1, 0) * 2

comb3(1, 0) = 1  (k equals to 0, it returns 1)

comb3(2, 1) = 1 * 2 = 2

comb3(3, 2) = 2 * 1 = 2
```

The issue is that when I run the code I obtain `3`, but I don't understand why.

Comment: You know that `3/2` yields different results in Python 2 vs 3, yes? And this `comb3` function will potentially yield different results too, for the same input.

Comment: Hi jarmod, also I got same result in c++ defining it as an int function, and I obtain the same result. The question is that is ok my understanding of this recursion statement and why I'm getting 3 instead of 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting 3 is,

in your first iteration,
The `if` check is false. So, it goes on to

`comb3(n-1, k-1) * n/k;`

That line above will resolve to

`comb3(3-1, 2-1) * 3/2;`

The next iteration will also skip the if check and result to

`comb3(2-1, 1-1) * 2/1;`

At this point, the if statement becomes true and you get a return value of 1.

then we multiply `3/2 * 2/1 * 1 = 3`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong, code is working as it should

```
comb3(3, 2) = comb3(2,1)*3/2
comb3(2, 1) = comb3(1,0)*2/1
comb3(1, 0) = 1

comb3(2, 1) = 1 * 2 / 1 = 2
comb3(3, 2) = 2 * 3 / 2 = 3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback, I was stucked thinking in the fact that 3/2 = 1, but I was not thinking in the operator hierarchy, from left to right: 2 * 3 / 2 = 6 / 2 = 3